# DAX: how to calculate sales on day before selected day of goods, which didn’t sale on selected date

Tags: dax

I have a table with sales on different dates. I have to calculate sales on day before selected day of goods, which didn’t sale on selected date. I wrote the measures and it calculate sum correct (on table visualization),  but when I put an goods group to the visualization, sum of components is not equal total sum. For example

1. Group1 = 1000;
2. Group2 = 3000;
   Total = 1000
   It should be because goods from Group2 migrate to Group3 on selected date
   Please help to fix it

```
MyMeasure=
VAR SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE(‘tSales’[SaleDate])
VAR PreviousDate = DATEADD(‘tSales’[SaleDate],-‘Parameters’[Period],MONTH)
RETURN
CALCULATE(
   SUM(‘tSales’[Revenue]),
   ‘tSales’[SaleDate] = PreviousDate && ‘tSales’[GoodsGroup] = “Group1”,
   NOT (‘tSales’[ID] IN CALCULATETABLE(
   VALUES(‘tSales’[ID]), ‘tSales’[SaleDate] = SelectedDate))
)
```